# MongoDB [Object: null prototype] when creating array of object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am having a problem pinpointing the data I need inside mongoDB. I created a hotel schema for my website and inside that, I have an array of objects. Now, after creating a list of hotels, There is a `[Object: null prototype]` also inside of the array.

here is the schema:

```
firstHotel: [
  {
  name: String,
  image: String,
  info: String, 
  description: String, 
  },
  {
    name: String,
    image: String,
    info: String, 
    description: String, 
  },
  {
    name: String,
    image: String,
    info: String, 
    description: String, 
  },
]
```

and this is what I use inside my ejs form

```
        <form method="POST">
            <!-- tour is what use in the req.body to collect all the request -->
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][0][name]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][0][image]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][0][info]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][0][description]">

            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][1][name]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][1][image]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][1][info]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][1][description]">

            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][2][name]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][2][image]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][2][info]">
            <input type="text" name="tour[firstHotel][2][description]">
    </form>
```

After clicking submit, here is the result inside mongo.

```
    firstHotel:
   [ [Object: null prototype] { name: '', image: '', info: '', description: '' },
     [Object: null prototype] { name: '', image: '', info: '', description: '' },
     [Object: null prototype] { name: '', image: '', info: '', description: '' } ],
```

I will use this data for a `forEach Method` in the show route of my website. But why is there a `[Object: null prototype]`

What is the proper way of defining a schema for an array of objects inside mongoose so the `[Object: null prototype]` will be gone.

I tried searching stackoverflow for an answer But I didn't find any. 
Hope you can help me ;-)

Comment: "*There is a `[Object: null prototype]` also inside of the array.*" - no, *each* of the three objects in the array has `null` as its prototype. This looks normal. Does anything not work, do you get any errors?

Comment: everything works but when I used a `forEach` in ejs to get the data, it is saying `name is not defined` `image is not defined` etc.

Comment: @Bergi, your comment gives me an idea and I solved it. Thank you

Comment: Can you please post the code that causes this error? Also if you solved it, you might want to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)